# Windows SubSystem Linuxでfontを変える

Tags: windows, windows-10, font, wsl

Windows SubSystem for Linuxでフォントを変えたいのですがどうすればよいのでしょうか?
[Source Han Code JP](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-han-code-jp)
というフォントを使いたいです。
windowsのコンソールはotfには対応しておらず、ttfしか使えないようなのでfontforgeでttfに変換してインストールしたのですが、wslの設定画面では、そのフォントを選択できません。

また、私の環境では、システムのデフォルトエンコーディングがutf-8になっています。
http://mitomoha.hatenablog.com/entry/2018/01/15/001210

OS: Windows 10 1803

Comment: WSL はコマンドプロンプトからも PowerShell からも起動することができますが、どちらを想定なさっていますか？

Comment: ご利用のコンソールがコマンドプロンプトであれば、フォントの追加にはレジストリの変更が必要なようです。以下に変更方法が記載されています。[Windows 10のコマンドプロンプトで任意のフォントを使う（Rictyも可）](https://holybea.com/2015/10/10/windows-10-cmd-fonts/)

Comment: スタートメニューから"Ubuntu 18.04"を開いた場合はどちらで開いていることになるのでしょうか?

Answer (score 2):

等幅かつTTFなフォント以外のフォントを選択できるWindowsの代替ターミナル(コマンドプロンプト等のコンソールの代わりになるソフト)として[ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/)(コマンドプロンプト等以外にもWSLにも使用可能)があります。ConEmu(またはそのラッパーである[cmder](http://cmder.net/))を使えば、Source Han Code JP(源ノ角ゴシック Code JP)を設定で選択し、使用することが出来ます。

ただし、この方法にはSource Han Code JP特有の問題により、漢字・仮名が表示された文字(グリフ)よりもかなり幅が大きくなるという問題があります。通常の等幅フォント(monospace font)では、英数字:漢字・仮名の幅比率が1:2ですが、Source Han Code JPは2:3と特殊です。ConEmuで等幅フォントを処理する場合、一般的な1:2を前提にしているため、漢字・仮名を英数字の2倍幅として枠を取ろうとするせいか、比率がおかしくなってグリフに対して幅が大きくなり、見た目が悪くなってしまいます。これではSource Han Code JPを使う意味がありません。(ConEmuは二つ以上のフォントを組み合わせることが出来ますが、幅を調整することがどうしても出来ませんでした。)

[image: cmderで検証]

他に、有名な代替ターミナルとして[mintty](https://mintty.github.io/)があります。こちらもコンソールと同じく等幅かつTTFなフォントしか選択できないようですが、設定ファイル(.minttyrc)で無理矢理フォントを設定することが出来ます。その場合は英数字も縦に対して横が等しい幅になってしまい、そこから漢字・仮名が英数字の2倍幅になって、全体としてグリフに対して幅が常に大きくなります。

[image: MSYS2のminttyで検証]

---

ということで、Source Han Code JPをまともに使うことを求めるなら、もっと別の代替ターミナルを探すが、オープンソースであるConEmuやminttyのソースを書き換えるしかないと思われます。そこまでこわわりがなければ、源真ゴシックや更紗ゴシックなどの等幅かつTTFでSource Han Sansを使ったフォントを使用した方が良いのではないかと思われます。